# Make sure object key belongs to a defined set

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create an object type that can only accept a defined set of keys. In the example below, `'1.1.1' | '1.1.2' | '1.1.3'`.

Assume that `levelNum, subLevelNum and problemNum` are valid strings within the set.

```
type AllowedIndexes = '1.1.1' | '1.1.2' | '1.1.3';
type ProblemType = { [index in AllowedIndexes]?: Problem };

let problems: ProblemType = {};

// --> the following line gives the error <--
// `TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type AllowedIndex.`
let ix:AllowedIndexes = `${levelNum}.${subLevelNum}.${problemNum}`;

problems[ix] = new Problem(....)
```

However, if I write the faulty line as below, it works :

```
let ix:AllowedIndexes = `${levelNum}.${subLevelNum}.${problemNum}` as AllowedIndexes;
```

Am I going the right way, or am I totally off to make sure the object key belongs to a defined set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're correct in here.

This line

```
let ix:AllowedIndexes = `${levelNum}.${subLevelNum}.${problemNum}`;
```

Tell's TypeScript you're trying to assign template string (which is of type `string`) to a value which expected type is `AllowedIndexes`. However TypeScript cannot be sure that this will always be true and with your modification:

```
let ix:AllowedIndexes = `${levelNum}.${subLevelNum}.${problemNum}` as AllowedIndexes;
```

You're explicitly telling it that the value will be indeed `AllowedIndexes`. From the type perspective it is correct, it might not be correct from the logical/runtime perspective when one of `levelNum`, `subLevelNum` or `problemNum` variables will be incorrect, but TypeScript cannot know that in this case. The only improvement to this code that I can think of is to use built-in `Record` type for `ProblemType` like so:

```
type ProblemType = Partial<Record<AllowedIndexes, Problem>>;
```

Note that I added `Partial` only because you specified your object's props as optional with `?`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to constrain the content of a string in ts beyond simple equality with string literal types.

Maybe use a tuple type instead, you can constrain it to be of a specific length and use literal types to specify the valid domain for each item in the tuple. Also you could use custom type assertions or type guards to narrow the type if your parts start form strings:

```
type AllowedIndexesItem = "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9" | "0";
type AllowedIndexes = [AllowedIndexesItem, AllowedIndexesItem, AllowedIndexesItem];

declare let problemNum: string;
declare let subLevelNum: string;
declare let levelNum: string;

function assertAllowedIndexesItem(o: string): asserts o is AllowedIndexesItem {
    if (!(o.length == 1 && o >= "0" && o < "9")) {
        throw new Error("Invlaid value")
    }
}
assertAllowedIndexesItem(levelNum);
assertAllowedIndexesItem(subLevelNum);
assertAllowedIndexesItem(problemNum);
let ix:AllowedIndexes = [levelNum, subLevelNum, problemNum];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA9gdwgEwJIDs0QB4QDOGwEAtlALxQBEAjDVAD60BMjLNAzB7QCy8aAVkEA2QQHZBADkEBOQQAYaAbgBQoSLAQp02XAUJUoAbXhJUmHPiIlyAGm0W91w3bKPzuqwdukyALrqargAxnAAhgBO0HAQwFBgUYgARnFkAHIArmQAXFCEwFEAllgA5uphkTFQcQmEWSkAMhAAbhBw2XkFRaUVIRDh0bHxtW0dXfmFJeXBAGZZWKHAxYhYUBGEhBBRwF6W+jbE-gAUiFO95QCU+Zvbu0aIUMVG+y6+x+RQAN5qUP-POZQE4AQjOADo4uVgAALKjUOhQABkSKgTwAfNQaMpkaingAeWgKK5XH5-AEU2HJZBQLAQGkAUSiySiJxo2FakWKaCgrQicCyEBoV3J-wAvmoJXcdnsdAdXH5yCc4u1Ojkruppbs3j4ju4Tg1muM1WQNWotbLnLq3Kckql0l0zXVnnhcjrDoZjCYVRMco5DS1VV1HHa0uQukE1GogA)